# drawing a circle between spheres

Tags: geometry

If I have 4 spheres arranged touching each other.

How can I find the diameter of the largest sphere that can fit inside the void region and touch them?

(The diameter of the largest inscribed sphere in the void should be a function of the diameter of the four spheres).

$$ d = f( d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4) $$

Comment: How many rows are there? Should there always be 8 circles in a row? If there are more than two rows, are each row always to the right of the preceding? What, precisely, is the boundary of "the region"? Is it the periphery of the relevant circles in some outermost row? And is "the void" the same as "the region"?

Comment: @Lovsovs Just imagine two rows (Though there could be more). The number of Rows does not necessarily matter. Just imagine a close packed system. Here is a link that shows the close-pack system: https://chemistry.osu.edu/~woodward/ch754/str_cp.htm

Comment: By region, do you then mean the void in between any three spheres that touch each other?

Comment: @Lovsovs Yes, that is what I mean. (sorry i wasnt clearer)

Comment: Okay, great. And no problem :) Uh, I think I know the solution, just a sec!

Comment: Did my solution make sense? Otherwise just let me know and I'll elaborate.

Comment: @Lovsovs i think so, so that is the radius of the largest circle we could draw in the void?

Comment: Yes indeed it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take three of the circles in the close-packed structure that all touch. The distance from one's center to the next is $2R$, where $R$ is the radius of either circle.
2. Connect the three centers to get an equilateral triangle.
3. Connect the vertices to the centroid (the intersection of the three bisectors). The distance from vertex to centroid is $L=\frac{2R}{\sqrt{3}}$.
4. Notice that the radius $r$ of the small circle is just $L-R$.

So we have
$$r=R \left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}-1 \right) \approx 0.1547R$$