# Minimal volume of $n$ efficiently packed spheres

Tags: reference-request, volume, spheres, packing-problem

Suppose there are $n$ spheres that we label $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Then suppose that the center $p_i$ of each of these spheres cannot be within distance $r$ of any other sphere. I would like to find out some information related to the most efficient way of packing these spheres.

Specifically, let us denote a sphere of radius $r$ at position $p$ by $S(p,r)$. Are there references available, or known sequences, that describe the following quantity?

$$V_{n} = \min_{p_1, \ldots, p_n} \left\{ \operatorname{volume} \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n S(p_i,r)\right) \mid \operatorname{distance}(p_i,p_j) \geq r\ \forall i,j \right\}$$

Of particular interest is the two-dimensional case.

Comment: That's funny, I *just* answered a question that's a bit similar to this one (with regard to the 2D-case). I find the minimum distance allowed in your case ($r=$ the radius of the spheres): http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1656944/259085
Let me know if you have any questions regarding it.

Comment: You need to more clearly define what you mean by "volume" of that region. Is it the volume of the smallest convex shape containing each sphere?

Comment: $r$ is both the minimum distance between centers and also the radius of the spheres? Then the spheres can overlap? Is really that what you mean?

Comment: @leonbloy I guess that since they are spheres, increasing $r$ is completely equivalent to increasing the radii of the spheres.

Comment: Btw, I think the wikipedia-page has your back: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres

Comment: @Lovsovs This seems to be a different problem: in spheres packing the spheres don't overlap, hence the total volume is constant. Here the spheres overlap.

Comment: @leonbloy I might not have understood then question then, but wouldn't you agree that taking a number of points and requiring that they should be more than some distance $r$ to each other and then packing them as close a possible is the same as the packing of spheres with radius $r$?. If not, why?

Comment: @Soke - The volume of the union of all spheres, which is less than the smallest convex shape that contains all spheres. See this by considering n = 2 in two dimensions. The shape will be a figure eight, which is not convex.

Comment: @leonbloy - The spheres can overlap.

Comment: @Lovsovs / leonbloy - You are right in noticing that this covering problem can be related to a packing problem of spheres with radius r/2. Though I'm specifically interested in the total volume (area) covered.

Comment: @Lovsovs Read the statement, the quantity to minimize is cleary stated. We are not interested in minimizing the boundary of the volume but the total volume occupied by the (union of) (overlapping) spheres. This is not the classical sphere packing problem (where the total volume of the union of the spheres is constant)

Comment: @leonbloy Yeah, I just realized that by looking through the first of your links. Great work finding those!

Answer (score 1):

Some material on Sphere Packing
with Overlap:

http://www.carolineuhler.com/Uhler_sphere_packing.pdf

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0468v1.pdf